# PHP: Echoing class on one element effects all elements echoed by loop

Tags: php, css, loops

I have a loop that echoes out some elements. I also have an if statement that applies the  check box 'checked' attribute to a checkbox element if it contains a certain string from the database, eg:

```
if ($team ==  $row['team1']) {
  $checked1 = "checked='checked'";
}
else {
  $checked1 = "";
}
if ($team ==  $row['team2']) {
  $checked2 = "checked='checked'";
}
else {
  $checked2 = "";
}

echo "<div><input type='radio' name='games" . $i . "' value='" . $row['team1'] . "' " . $checked1 . "></div>";
echo "<div><input type='radio' name='games" . $i . "' value='" . $row['team2'] . "' " . $checked2 . "></div>";
```

This seems to work fine. But I also want to add a class to the div surrounding the check box, eg:

```
if ($team ==  $row['team1']) {
  $checked1 = "checked='checked'";
  $div1 = "class='green'";
}
else {
  $checked1 = "";
  $div1 = "";
}
if ($team ==  $row['team2']) {
  $checked2 = "checked='checked'";
  $div2 = "class='green'";
}
else {
  $checked2 = "";
  $div2 = "";
}

echo "<div " . $div1 . "><input type='radio' name='games" . $i . "' value='" . $row['team1'] . "' " . $checked1 . "></div>";
echo "<div " . $div2 . "><input type='radio' name='games" . $i . "' value='" . $row['team2'] . "' " . $checked2 . "></div>";
```

The thing is the class seems to apply its self to all divs indescriminatly that are produced by the loop. Is this something that just occurs as a by product of looping and echoing out elements? Is there a better way of achieving this (perhaps with JQuery).

EDIT: Added HTML results

```
<div class='green'><input  type='radio' name='games1' value='myteam' checked='checked'></div>"
<div><input type='radio' name='games1' value='yourteam' ></div>

<div class='green'><input  type='radio' name='games1' value='myteam' ></div>"
<div><input type='radio' name='games1' value='yourteam' checked='checked'></div>

<div class='green'><input  type='radio' name='games1' value='myteam' ></div>"
<div><input type='radio' name='games1' value='yourteam' checked='checked'></div>

<div class='green'><input  type='radio' name='games1' value='myteam' checked='checked'></div>"
<div><input type='radio' name='games1' value='yourteam' ></div>"
```

Comment: This doesn't look very efficient at all. I also don't understand what you mean by "apply its self to all divs." Can you show the HTML that's produced?

Comment: You might want to show us your loop code too...

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I have added the html results above. As you can see, the class always applies its self to the first div, where I want it to apply to the div that contains the checked radio button

Comment: @MeltingDog What's your loop look like?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk ok...its massive and complicated. The above is part of a much larger script. I have created this fiddle to help http://jsfiddle.net/7A3ab/

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with your loop, however I would try to declare the variables before your logic.

This will ensure that they are cleared each time around:

```
$checked1 = "";
$div1 = "";
$checked2 = "";
$div2 = "";

if ($team ==  $row['team1']) {
  $checked1 = ' checked="checked"';
  $div1 = ' class="green"';
}

if ($team ==  $row['team2']) {
  $checked2 = ' checked="checked"';
  $div2 = ' class="green"';
}

echo '<div' . $div1 . '><input type="radio" name="games' . $i . '" value="' . $row['team1'] . '"' . $checked1 . '></div>';
echo '<div' . $div2 . '><input type="radio" name="games' . $i . '" value="' . $row['team2'] . '"' . $checked2 . '></div>';
```

Also, if `$team` is empty, and `$row[team1]` is empty, it will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

(I would leave a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Anyway, is there a reason you have this:

```
$div1 ="class='green'";
$div2 ="class='green'";
```

? All your classes will look the same when both variables have the same value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. FYI, you can use the `{}` button on the tool bar or tick marks ie "`" to format code snippets.